single_version_override with patch = [...] has no effect
I'm trying to use the single_version_override feature of MODULES.bazel in order to apply a local patch to an existing public repository in the Bazel Common Registry. (Specifically google_benchmark doesn't build on an arm64 windows system and I want to both locally unblock playing with it and eventually work on upstreaming a fix if they're interested in taking it).
While trying to use single_version_override with a patches = ["//:foo.patch"], I've been unable to get the patch to have an effect on the dependent repository.
Using "//:does_not_exist.patch" as a patch cause the build to fail (good). Setting version = "$different_version" cause bazel (which for my is an alias to bazelisk) to rebuild the repo (good).

But as far as I can tell changing the contents of the patch doesn't trigger a rebuild of anything in the repository. Setting the patch to create an invalid repsitory isn't causing things to fail. Setting patch_level = 0 (or 1 or 2) also doesn't cause anything to fail (and I would expect at least one level to fail).
I've attempted these things on both my Windows ARM box as well as a Mac laptop (the Windows ARM being in a VM on the Mac).
I can't figure out what to do to debug more deeply and any help would be appreciated.
I'm going to include an example, but I specifically am asking for help on how to debug this sort of thing, not an answer to my specific problem. I can't find any documentation on how to debug when these sorts of rules go awry, and even if I get an answer to this problem, the fact that I don't have any way of debugging when these don't work is what worries me.
For example, I start with this (simple) repo: https://github.com/monkeynova/gunit-main
bazel test ...
works just fine.
If I include the following at the end of MODULES.bazel
single_version_override(
    module_name = "google_benchmark",
    patches = ["//:benchmark.patch"],
)

with the following (broken -- note the "this is not valid") patch:
benchmark.patch
diff --git a/BUILD.bazel b/BUILD.bazel
index 094ed62..49f2f56 100644
--- a/BUILD.bazel
+++ b/BUILD.bazel
@@ -35,6 +35,15 @@ config_setting(
     visibility = [":__subpackages__"],
 )
 
+config_setting(
+    name = "arm_windows",
+    constraint_values = ["@platforms//os:windows"],
+    values = {
+        "cpu": "arm64_windows",
+    },
+    visibility = [":__subpackages__"],
+)
+
+ this is invalid
+
 config_setting(
     name = "macos",
     constraint_values = ["@platforms//os:macos"],
@@ -64,6 +73,7 @@ cc_library(
     ],
     copts = select({
         ":windows": [],
+        ":arm_windows": [],
         "//conditions:default": COPTS,
     }),
     defines = [
@@ -76,6 +86,7 @@ cc_library(
     includes = ["include"],
     linkopts = select({
         ":windows": ["-DEFAULTLIB:shlwapi.lib"],
+        ":arm_windows": ["-DEFAULTLIB:shlwapi.lib"],
         "//conditions:default": ["-pthread"],
     }),
     # Only static linking is allowed; no .so will be produced.

It continues to build and test fine. If I specify the wrong file the build fails. If I remove the "this is not valid", this is the patch that I created from git diff on a successful patch to a local_path_override.

I'm not sure about the incrementality of single_version_override, but you could try checking out the google_benchmark repo and using local_path_override instead: https://bazel.build/rules/lib/globals/module#local_path_override Might be easier to work with in iterative development than a patch anyway.

I have done that to confirm my changes have the desired effect. But I can't check in my repo this way as that would require all locations I use to have the same magic path. What I'm looking for is a way for me to be able to not have to be super careful about local, unchecked-in changes.

Is the problem that you're not seeing the patch do anything at all with single_version_override or that single_version_override doesn't update when you change the patch? If the 2nd one, it looks like you can get a working patch with local_path_override then use that patch with single_version_override. Again not sure if patches in single_version_override are intended to be incremental or not or if that's a bug.

The problem is that I can't see an effect from the patch. Like I do the local_path_override from a git repo that I alter. I 'git diff > foo.patch' and use that with single_version_override and while local_path_override builds, the single_version_override doesn't. And I've gone and corrupted the patch in various ways where attempts to patch should fail but don't.

Can you update your question with a repro example?

I've included an example, but as I tried to highlight, I'm looking for help on how to debug (i.e. "teach a man to fish") not the specific answer here. "Debug by expert inspection" leaves me unable to do better the next time I want to use a random bazel feature.

And it looks like this might be a known issue: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/pull/23536

Nope. Digging deeper that looks like a different issue...

I found the problem: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/23843

Glad you were able to get to the bottom of this

For the general problem of debugging here, I resorted to editing the bazel source code to add "System.err.printf" at several points in the patching code. This feels unfortunate, but given I stumbled on something in bazel I would classify as a bug (reported below) this may not be unexpected.
It was able to show me that my problem was that my patch was formed in a way that the custom bazel patch code couldn't recognize. The patch was constructed in a non-utf8 charset that all text rendering I found hid from me. (od -hc was the tool I used to confirm my suspicions).
For the specific problem I encountered, I found the bug and reported it: github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/23843
